# "from" vs. "off" when talking about an album track

Tags: prepositions

Is there a difference in the meaning or use of those two phrases:

> - Favorite track **off** *Dark Side of the Moon*
> - Favorite track **from** *Dark Side of the Moon*

Is one of them wrong or not as correct as the other?

What situations we use "off" in?

Comment: It's a little less formal to use "off" in that context. Otherwise no problem.

Comment: The word _on_ could work, too: _'Money' is my favorite track **on** 'Dark Side of the Moon'_. Incidentally, your last question ("What situations we use "off" in?") seems a [little broad](http://www.wordnik.com/words/off) – the word _off_ can be used in **dozens** of situations.

Comment: I dont know how could I have gotten any more specific than this, Im sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Off* as a preposition is well established in a literal sense of movement:

> He climbed off the roof.

But in a figurative sense, meaning the same as *from*, it is common, but colloquial; most people would not consider it appropriate in formal writing.

> I got it from/?off John.

[For some speakers there is another colloquial variant: *off of*. This is also not usually accepted in formal writing].